# Como eu faço para usar potência em C++?

Tags: c++

Estou fazendo uma calculadora simples, e queria adicionar potência.

Já tentei `Pow()` e não deu, precisa adicionar alguma classe?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### Não é `Pow`, é `pow`.

Maíusculas e minúsculas fazem diferença em C++

E a biblioteca é a `math`:

```
#include <math.h>

int main ()
{
  printf ("5 ^ 3 = %f\n", pow(5.0, 3.0));
  return 0;
}
```

Veja funcionando na **[IDEONE](https://ideone.com/Dgh23e)**.

Comment: Vlw^^ é que eu sou iniciante. Deu certinho.